# iPad won't turn on after being drained

Tags: ios, ipad, battery, power, charge

What if my iPad didn't turn on after battery drain?
I did all the steps but it still didn't work.
Is it already damaged or can I recover it on an Apple Store?

Comment: What would this steps be?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, apparently my iPad couldn't be any more charged. So I brought it to a shop, and voila, they could charge it. Point being to really really use the original "fat" charger and not another one (like the thin one of an iPhone). The chargers differ in the maximal current they can supply (more than 2A is needed for the iPad).